# MATLAB: Entering multiple input values for the x-axis in a graph

Tags: matlab, input

The MATLAB program below is a function that references specific input values for S, E, r, sigma, and tau.

```
function [C, Cdelta, P, Pdelta] = ch08(S,E,r,sigma,tau)

% Input arguments: S = asset price at time t
%                  E = Exercise price
%                  r = interest rate
%                  sigma = volatility
%                  tau = time to expiry (T-t) 
%
% Output arguments: C = call value, Cdelta = delta value of call 
%                   P = Put value, Pdelta = delta value of put
%
%   function [C, Cdelta, P, Pdelta] = ch08(S,E,r,sigma,tau)

if tau > 0
   d1 = (log(S/E) + (r + 0.5*sigma^2)*(tau))/(sigma*sqrt(tau));
   d2 = d1 - sigma*sqrt(tau);
   N1 = 0.5*(1+erf(d1/sqrt(2)));
   N2 = 0.5*(1+erf(d2/sqrt(2)));
   C = S*N1-E*exp(-r*(tau))*N2;
   Cdelta = N1;
   P = C + E*exp(-r*tau) - S;
   Pdelta = Cdelta - 1;
   title('Graph of Call Value vs. Time to Expiry')
   xlabel('Time to expiry')
   ylabel('Call Value')
   plot (tau,C)
else 
   C = max(S-E,0);
   Cdelta =  0.5*(sign(S-E) + 1);
   P = max(E-S,0);
   Pdelta = Cdelta - 1;
   title('Graph of Call Value vs. Time to Expiry')
   xlabel('Time to expiry')
   ylabel('Call Value')
   plot (tau,C)
end
```

After running

```
ch08(3,2.5,0.03,0.25,1)
```

The following output is produced

[image: Graph 1]

After running the function again,

```
ch08(3,2.5,0.03,0.25,1)
hold on
ch08(3,2.5,0.03,0.25,0.9)
```

Two data points are produced

[image: Graph 2]

After manually typing decreasing tau values,

```
ch08(3,2.5,0.03,0.25,1)
hold on
ch08(3,2.5,0.03,0.25,0.9)
hold on
ch08(3,2.5,0.03,0.25,0.8)
hold on
ch08(3,2.5,0.03,0.25,0.7)
hold on
ch08(3,2.5,0.03,0.25,0.6)
hold on
ch08(3,2.5,0.03,0.25,0.5)
hold on
ch08(3,2.5,0.03,0.25,0.4)
hold on
ch08(3,2.5,0.03,0.25,0.3)
hold on
ch08(3,2.5,0.03,0.25,0.2)
hold on
ch08(3,2.5,0.03,0.25,0.1)
```

The graph will produce a bunch of data points,

[image]

Is there a way to automate the tau values entered in ch08(S,E,r,sigma,**tau**) so that the user doesn't have to type all of the input in?

Comment: This is very basic. There are lots of good tutorials online that will get you started in MATLAB, it's a less painful way to learn than asking questions on SO. Look for the use of `for` and indexing and basic array creation.

Comment: I agree that the for loop is extremely basic. I'm stuck on putting the results from the for loop into the x-axis on plot(x,y),

Comment: Show what you have accomplished so far, that makes it easier to answer.

Comment: Did you try `tau=10.^(0:-1:-6)` and `tau(i)` and `y(i)=C`?

Comment: I found the problem through trial and error, rephrasing question.

Comment: I've posted an answer that I hope will be useful. However, I reiterate, it would be a lot easier for you to learn the MATLAB language by reading some of the tutorials. These are really useful: https://www.mathworks.com/support/learn-with-matlab-tutorials.html

Comment: A better way of solving this whole problem would be to vectorise your code and accept an array of `tau` values, therefore only having to call the function once. But I sense that's probably beyond the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in comments, you need to use a `for` loop. You can create an array with values of `tau` that you want to use, and call your function with a different element from that array in each loop iteration:

```
figure, hold on
tau = 10.^(0:-1:-6);
for ii = 1:length(tau)
   ch08(3,2.5,0.03,0.25,tau(ii))
end
```

However, a better solution would be to not plot within your `ch08` function, and return the value `C` as you did in your first version of your question. Then you can do this:

```
tau = 10.^(0:-1:-6);
C = zeros(size(tau));
for ii = 1:length(tau)
   C(ii) = ch08(3,2.5,0.03,0.25,tau(ii));
end
plot(tau,C,'.');
```

This would allow you to change your plot as you please, for example drawing a line through your points.

PS: Note that you only need to give `hold on` once. It sets a flag in the figure window that is not cleared until you do `hold off` or `clf`.

Comment: As a note, the OP's example has been edited and now uses `tau=1:-0.1:0.1` rather than `tau= 10.^(0:-1:-6)`

Comment: I have modified the program and am watching the tutorials to learn MATLAB. I apologize for being a beginner and am grateful for the help.